# How to make background worker works with delay or timer

Tags: c#

I`m really new into coding and i need your help.

I watched some tutorials and i`ve made simple trainer for an offline game.
But i need some help for updates that i want to make. So thats the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Memory;


namespace ******
{

  public partial class CheatMenu : Form
{
    public CheatMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Mem m = new Mem();       

    private void CheatMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {           
        {
            int pID = m.getProcIDFromName("****"); //get proc id of game       

            bool openProc = false; //is process open?

            if (pID > 0) openProc = m.OpenProcess(pID); //try opening process if proc ID is greater than 1.

            if (openProc) //if process open, do code
            {             
                if (disableWarden.Checked) //if checked, disable warden.
                    m.writeMemory("0x05D9B364", "byte", "0x45");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So this memory address is some kind of character animation and when i write memory into it and lock it with this code char starts move really fast. With cheat engine when i make update locked values interval time less it slows down (as low as value is the char moves slower)

So with that in mind i need to set some kind of timer into backgroundworker. Could you guys help me with that.
Keep in mind i`m really really new into coding.

Thanks !

Comment: Why would you place this on a background worker? You could use the Windows.Forms.Timer for that. Because the write action code is very short in duration.

Comment: I tried to use timer but the code does not work. Maybe i made some mistake.